# Сортировка queryset по заданному условию в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, queryset

Есть модель Clan, у которой есть CharField(строковое) поле title.
Мне необходимо отсортировать все объекты этой модели по данному полю, но по заданному условию - необходимо отсортировать объекты по частоте встречи данной подстроки в названии(title) клана(Clan)

Следующий способ сортирует по умолчанию, как я помню в лексикографическом порядке:

```
Clan.objects.order_by('title')
```

Мне же нужно отсортировать все модели клана по частоте встречи в них заданной подстроки --> в данном случае пусть эта строка будет `'clan'`. То есть получится должно что-то такое(но это не работает, в данном случае двойной андерскор указывает на сортировку по полю модели, после которой он употребляется - а у нас имеется в виду строка)

```
Clan.objects.order_by("title__contains='clan'")
```

Также хотелось бы узнать как отсортировать/отфильтровать объекты кланов по отсутствию в них заданной подстроки

Comment: По частоте встречи в них заданной подстроки? То есть примерно так `['Clan spam clan eggs clan', 'clan qwerty clan', 'clan foo', 'bar']`?

Comment: Ну да, чтобы в результирующем списке были названия всех кланов, отсортированных по частоте встречи в них заданной подстроки. Соответственно, если в названии есть слово 'clan' оно должно быть в списке полностью, а не только часть с этим словом. И если слова в названии нет, оно все равно должно быть в списке, только где-то в конце

Comment: Пока что есть идея только слияния двух списков: первый - отфильтрованный queryset по условию встречи в названии заданной подстроки, второй - все элементы исходного queryset, которые не встречаются в первом списке. Я вот хотел узнать, нет ли уже готовой функции по сортировке

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, что я правильно понял условия.

Я бы при сохранении каждой записи автоматически считал количество слов в заголовке и клал это значение в отдельное поле, "word_occurrence", например.

Тогда сортировку было бы очень просто сделать простым запросом:

```
Clan.objects.order_by('word_occurrence')
```

Для этого нужно переписать метод `save()` у модели. [Пример из документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods)

Если интересно, то позже постараюсь добавить пример кода.

Плюс в том, что не нужно строить сложные запросы или каждый раз считать что-то при запросе к БД.

Что касается кастомной сортировки. Я не знаю как можно сделать такой запрос, используя Django ORM. Но можно получить список объектов и отсортировать его с помощью функции sorted()

Пример со списокм:

```
clan_titles = ['111', 'clan vvv clan', 'clan']


# Функция для подсчета количества слов "clan" в строке
def word_count(clan_title):
    return sum([1 for word in clan_title.split() if word == 'clan'])    

# Просто проверяем, что считает правильно
for title in clan_titles:
    print(word_count(title))

# Используем функцию подсчета слов в качестве ключа для сортировки
srtd = sorted(clan_titles, key=word_count, reverse=True)

print(srtd)
```

Я не имею сейчас возможности протестировать то же самое с queryset'ами. Но это может выглядеть так:

```
clans_qs = list(Clan.objects.all())


def word_count(clan_obj):
    return sum([1 for word in clan_obj.title.split() if word == 'clan'])    


srtd = sorted(clan_qs, key=word_count, reverse=True)

print(srtd)
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложенный способ, но мне нужно было узнать нет ли какой-либо встроенной функции в Django. К тому же ваш способ не до конца функционален - хороший поисковой запрос даст результат не просто разделив слова на группы: входит подстрока в название / не входит. То есть сначала должны идти названия, в которых есть вхождения сразу трех подстрок "clan", после этого двух, потом одной и после этого должны быть отсортированы и остальные результаты - названия в которые входит подстрока "cla" должны идти раньше, чем те, в которых встречается лишь "cl". А в конце идут совпадения лишь с одной "c"